# java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'OPTION'

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, ambari

I am installing MYSQL with Ambari server for hadoop installation on ubuntu.

I have My Sql installed from Xampp and works fine.

The set `Option keyword has been removed from My SQL 5.6 version and mariaDB (comes with xampp) is consistent with that.

The website shows it is compatible with MySQL 5.6 version which should be fine.

In response to [the only relevant link I found](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-6201),

when I check for my sql version:

```
mysql -v
The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-core-5.6
 * mariadb-client-core-10.0
```

This is what I get. I believe the problem mentioned in the link is not the case here then?

When I try to register my host with ambari server, it throws this errror:

I have tried replacing connectors, versions and everything I could. But I keep getting this error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'OPTION'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.unsetMaxRows(Connection.java:5867)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.realClose(Statement.java:2070)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.realClose(PreparedStatement.java:2204)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.close(PreparedStatement.java:695)
    at com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:41)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache.synchronousDestroyStatement(GooGooStatementCache.java:413)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache.closeAll(GooGooStatementCache.java:351)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.closeAllCachedStatements(NewPooledConnection.java:598)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:468)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:191)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:470)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:964)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner
```

Comment: Check [this](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-6201) on JIRA, it should help you

Comment: @JadChahine: Ofcourse I did. I do not have sql 5.5 anywhere on my system and I am using mariadb 10.0. Please check the update .

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and updating mysql driver version fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, I also reinstalled the new version of xampp,jdk with jre and Netbeans,then problem solved